# How to use Sequelize bulkCreate to enter multiple rows of data with different values

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, sequelize.js, crud

So I'm trying to use Sequelize bulkCreate to enter mutiple rows of data into my database for one table. I have a table with input groups to enter in one set data as well as a function to create a new row in my table on a button click to add more data. When I hit submit, the data gets inserted as an array of objects into one row instead of splitting up the data into multiple rows. Any ideas on how to separate the data into multiple row? On top of that, the last two columns are datatypes of real and when I submit the data to the database the values get entered as NaN.

Controller

```js
const { project_id, imp_or_ann, category, cost, hours } = req.body;

        try {
            
            const costHours = await Prjt_costs_hours.bulkCreate([
                {project_id, imp_or_ann, category, cost, hours},
                {project_id, imp_or_ann, category, cost, hours},
                {project_id, imp_or_ann, category, cost, hours},
                {project_id, imp_or_ann, category, cost, hours},
            ]);

            return res.redirect('/fundings')

        } catch (error) {

            console.error(error.message);
            return res.status(500).json(error);
            
        }
    }
```

Model

```js
Prjt_costs_hours.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    project_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: false
    },
    imp_or_ann: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: false
    },
    category: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: false
    },
    cost: DataTypes.REAL,
    hours: DataTypes.REAL
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Prjt_costs_hours',
    tableName: 'prjt_costs_hours',
    timestamps: false
  });
  return Prjt_costs_hours;
};
```

HTML

```html
<form action='/costs_hours' method="POST">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Costs and Hours</h1>
        <div class="card border-secondary w-100 text-light" style="background-color: #333f48">
            <div style="background-color: #bf5700;" class="card-header text-end">
                <button style="background-color: #333f48" class='btn text-light' id="addRow" type="button">Add another
                    row</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body w-100 text-end">
                <table id="tableData" class="table text-light text-center mt-3">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Project ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Implementation or Annual</th>
                            <th scope="col">Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Costs</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hours</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input name="project_id" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <select name="imp_or_ann" class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                            <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                                            <option>Implementation</option>
                                            <option>Annual</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <select name="category" class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                            <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                                            <option>EMO</option>
                                            <option>Analysts</option>
                                            <option>Maintenance</option>
                                            <option>ETS</option>
                                            <option>BOT</option>
                                            <option>OtherUT</option>
                                            <option>Materials</option>
                                            <option>Non-UT Contract</option>
                                            <option>Contingency</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input name="cost" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input name="hours" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" style="background-color: #bf5700;" class="btn btn-warning text-light">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Database entry

```
1   "{Test,Test,Test,Test}" "{Implementation,Annual,Implementation,Annual}" "{EMO,Analysts,Maintenance,BOT}"    NaN NaN
2   "{Test,Test,Test,Test}" "{Implementation,Annual,Implementation,Annual}" "{EMO,Analysts,Maintenance,BOT}"    NaN NaN
3   "{Test,Test,Test,Test}" "{Implementation,Annual,Implementation,Annual}" "{EMO,Analysts,Maintenance,BOT}"    NaN NaN
4   "{Test,Test,Test,Test}" "{Implementation,Annual,Implementation,Annual}" "{EMO,Analysts,Maintenance,BOT}"    NaN NaN
```

Comment: When you destructure the input from the `req.body` make sure they aren't all strings and that you are inserting the correct types.

Comment: Theyre defined as strings in my model. Is that whats causing the issue?